# How do I reassign a point's XY value in ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-9.3, utm, xy

I have a rectangle polygon I drew on a map and then added points to it's corner and midpoint. I drew the shape (representing a forest sample plot) where I thought it was best located based on 70 year old hand drawn maps. However, I now know the exact GPS coordinates (UTM) of the plot and would like to move the shape and points on my map to the correct GPS points.

Is there a way to select these features and change their XY coordinates to match the UTM values I now have?

Comment: Why not create points and redraw them in a new feature class?

Comment: Is that the better way to go then? How do I do that?

Comment: Convert your coordinates to points, create new feature class (polygon), start editing it and go click-clik with your mouse. Make sure there is a circle above point, which means your next polygon vertex will be snapped to gps point. In 9.3 if memory serves you can set up snap environment

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure how to convert coordinates to points.

Comment: If GPS points have same ID for forest and are ordered along perimeter, try points to line if it was in 9.3, build polygons afterwards

Comment: Add XY layer tool

Comment: I added them, but they don't show up anywhere. Is this because everything else on my map has been converted to feet? How do I convert my UTM to feet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36807/discussion-between-felixip-and-theforestecologist).